# Spring batch FixedLengthTokenizer Range without upper limit is not working

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-batch

As per java doc of `Range` class

> A Range can be unbounded at maximum  * side. This can be specified by
>   passing {@link Range#UPPER_BORDER_NOT_DEFINED}} as max  * value or
>   using constructor {@link #Range(int)}

I have one like like

> SomeText sometext etc

**Update: InputFile**  Basically i have Multi line data set like this.**Itemid** is identifier of start of recorder. I am using `SingleItemPeekableItemReader` ,`PatternMatchingCompositeLineTokenizer` after lot of efforts , i got it working and was able read the the data in required pojo. the solution is build on

https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/4.0.x/reference/html/common-patterns.html#multiLineRecords.

But as

```
Itemid1-ID1
SomeRandomText1SomeRandomText1SomeRandomText1
SomeRandomText1
SomeRandomText1SomeRandomText1SomeRandomText1

Itemid2-ID2
SomeRandomText1SomeRandomText1
SomeRandomText1
SomeRandomText1
SomeRandomText1SomeRandomText1
```

The data item is like

```
class Pojo 
{
 String id
String data // this data is concatenated string of of all remaining lines. until 
           //new data iteam 

}
```

IF I want to configure `FixedLengthTokenizer` to read this in n single field

```
public FixedLengthTokenizer head()
    {
        FixedLengthTokenizer token = new FixedLengthTokenizer();
        token.setNames("id");
        token.setColumns(new Range(1));         
        return token;
    }
```

My Expectation is if i do not provide the max limit in Range constructor, then it will read the full line. But  i am getting **Line is longer than max range 1 Exception**

Can someone please help?

Comment: can you show the exception, please. Max value shoud be at `Integer.MAX_VALUE`...strange

Comment: Thanks pratik . If i add the Max value as token.setColumns(new Range(1,Integer.Max)); then i get error saying line is smaller that Integer.MAX

Comment: Maybe you should not use a `FixedLengthTokenizer` if you dont want to specifiy min and max. What about to use a `DelimitedLineTokenizer`?

Comment: What should be Delimited Value ? As i want to read the full value ?

Comment: Could be a Tab or Comma. Can you show some part of your file you want to read.

Comment: Thank you again Pratik for checking this.  updated the more details, But i am still not sure why the Range is not behaving as per java doc ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case, you need to specify two ranges: one for the ID and another one the actual data. Here is an example:

```
@Test
public void testFixedLengthTokenizerUnboundedRange() {
    FixedLengthTokenizer tokenizer = new FixedLengthTokenizer();
    tokenizer.setNames("id", "data");
    tokenizer.setColumns(new Range(1, 5), new Range(6));
    FieldSet tokens = tokenizer.tokenize("12345\nSomeRandomText1\nSomeRandomText2");
    assertEquals("12345", tokens.readString("id"));
    assertEquals("SomeRandomText1\nSomeRandomText2", tokens.readString("data"));
}
```

This test is passing. So the unbounded range is working as expected.

Hope the example helps.

Comment: Thanks, Mahmoud as of now I have use delimited o fix this issue, Will check this

Comment: Could you please check https://stackoverflow.com/q/52606370/320087 Question. This is an extension  of the same problem and need some help

Comment: answered the other question. hope it helps.

Comment: This does not addresses the problem in the correct context. Upper open range does not work for me either in the Spring Batch ItemReader implementation.

Comment: @MahmoudBenHassine - Could you please guide me here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63674370/caused-by-org-springframework-batch-item-file-transform-incorrectlinelengthexce ?